# Javascript getting text from html with hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
var label;
$('.card-label.mod-card-detail ').each((index, element) => {
    text = $(element).text().toUpperCase();
    switch(text){
        case "CODE REVIEW": 
            label = text;
            break;
        case "HOTFIX":
            if(label !== "CODE REVIEW") label = text;
            break;
        case "BUG":
            if(label !== "CODE REVIEW" && label !== "HOTFIX") label = text;
            break;
        case "FEATURE":
            if(label !== "CODE REVIEW" && label !== "HOTFIX" && label !== "BUG") label = text;
    }
})
```

I'm getting label names from html file. I need to apply label hierarchy: `CODE REVIEW -> HOTFIX -> BUG -> FEATURE`. Is there a way to make this code cleaner and more effective?

Comment: What do you tdo with this `label`? As is see it currently on every iteration you overwrite the previous value which makes it useless.

Comment: code edited i don't overwrite it every iteration

Comment: Still, you do. You [probably] need to make it local to the function, not a global variable. Currently, there is one `label` variable that is shared across all invocations of  the function, and each time the old value is overwritten.

Comment: That code _still_ overwrites `label` in every loop iteration (unless none of the cases match.) _How_ do you want to keep the hierarchy - do you want this to eventually return a nested array or object data structure? And _what_ hierarchy - show some example HTML as well. Go read [ask] and [mcve], please.

Comment: It overwrites only if the currently checked label is higher in hierarchy. Look at ifs. This code works, but I want to optimize it. I want to have the most important label name in my variable label.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it :

1. Create an object with label key and assign corresponding weight.
2. Push this object into array
3. use custom sort

```js
//Label texts : CODE REVIEW -> HOTFIX -> BUG -> FEATURE
//Corresponding weights : 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1


// decalre array 
var labelArr = [];
//push objects in switch case to this array
var labelText = {  
    text: 'CODE REVIEW' ,  
    weight: 4
};
var labelText1 = {  
    text: 'HOTFIX' ,  
    weight: 3
};
var labelText2 = {  
    text: 'BUG' ,  
    weight: 2
};
labelArr.push(labelText);
labelArr.push(labelText1);
labelArr.push(labelText2);



labelArr.sort(
          function(x, y)
          {
             return y.weight - x.weight ;
          }
        );
// Teatr White White 023 White flower
console.log(labelArr);
var finalLabel = labelArr.map(function(a) {return a.text;});
document.write(finalLabel.join('->'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an easier solution using just one go through the elements, no need for sort() or map():

```
var labels = ['FEATURE', 'BUG', 'HOTFIX', 'CODE REVIEW'],
    priority = -1;

$('.card-label.mod-card-detail ').each((index, element) => {
    let text = $(element).text().toUpperCase(),
        current_priority = labels.indexOf(text);

    // we found something with higher priority
    if(current_priority > priority) {
        priority = current_priority;
    }
});

if(priority < 0) {
    console.log("No labels found");
} else {
    let resulting_text = labels[priority];
    console.log("Highest priority found:", resulting_text);
}
```